# Can not deploy enterprise project to JBossAS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, ear

There is a simple EAR project with descriptor

[image: (screenshot from eclipse)]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application ... version="6">
  <display-name>EAR</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>View.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>view</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>Module.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

After deploy to Jboss7.1 I get errors

> WARN  [org.jboss.modules] Failed to define class
>   intf.module.FacadeLocal in Module "deployment.EAR.ear.Module.jar:main"
>   from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError :
>   intf/module/FacadeLocal : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 ...
>
> WARN  [org.jboss.modules] Failed to define class intf.module.Facade in
>   Module "deployment.EAR.ear.Module.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link intf/module/Facade
>   (Module "deployment.EAR.ear.Module.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: intf/module/FacadeLocal
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)[rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: intf.module.FacadeLocal
>   from [Module "deployment.EAR.ear.Module.jar :main" from Service Module
>   Loader] at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>
> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001:
>   Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR.ear"."Module.jar".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR.ear"."Module.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to
>   process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Module.jar" of deployment
>   "EAR.ear"
>
> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   Could not load EJB class intf.module.Facade
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: intf.module.Facade from
>   [Module "deployment.EAR.ear.Module.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

There are any errors in Eclipse but something went wrong. Could you point the problem here?

Comment: Your JBossAS instance is running an older version of Java than the one you used to build your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Eclipse, go to `Windows->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environment`

Edit the entry for `JBoss 7.1 Runtime`

Specify JRE as `[jre7]` - the one you are using in your java project to build it.

Click Finish and OK.

Restart the server.